# StructureMap LifeCycle of UnRegistered Types

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

In structuremap you can control the lifeCycle of an object you register, normally some interface to a concrete type as follows:

```
x.For<IMyInterface>().Transient().Use<MyObject>();
```

So I can control the life cycle. However when resolving objects (Concrete) types that are not registered the life cycle defaults to what seems to be Transient().

This is obviously a convenient feature of structuremap as I surely dont want to register each concrete type.

However is there  a way to override this life cycle without registration?

Furthermore it would be great if you can specify the life cycle of an object as an override much like:

```
ObjectFactory.With<SomeUnregisteredConcreteObject>().LifeCycleIs(...)
```

In such a case the life cycle would be modified for the next resolution to `GetInstance`

Any idea how any of this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a child container & register the component:

```
var child = ObjectFactory.Container.CreateChildContainer();
child.Configure(config => config.For<SomeUnregisteredConcreteType>().Singleton());
var @object = child.GetInstance<...>();
```

I assume that the reason why you didn't want to register was because you didn't want the registration to hang around. I think this solves that problem.

I also don't know of built-in a way to specify a default lifecycle. However, I think it's probably possible using the [`IAutoMocker`](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap.AutoMocking/AutoMocker.cs) interface. You could probably browse through the code in [that whole folder](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/tree/master/src/StructureMap.AutoMocking) to figure out how to do it. The AutoMocking hooks into the container so that a component is requested that isn't registered, it calls into the `IAutoMocker` and gives it a chance to register a component. I imagine that you could use `IAutoMocker` to register components with a different default lifecycle.

If you succeed in this, I hope you send a pull request or write a blog post to share with the rest of us.